# ¿Por qué me saca el assert vacío?

Tags: java, selenium

Hola estoy intentando sacar de una tabla HTML unas palabras de una celda en concreto con Selenium y Java, el problema es que cuando intento acceder a la celda en concreto de "FIN PESCADO", al hacer un `.getText()` no me saca el texto. Os dejo a continuación el código que esto usando:

Tabla:

```
<div class="x-grid-item-container" style="width: 1012px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <table id="gridview-1396-record-7" data-boundview="gridview-1396" data-recordid="7" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="  x-grid-row">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1392 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 126px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1392">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1393 x-unselectable" style="width: 550px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1393">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
                        <span>FIN PESCADO</span>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1394 x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1394">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1395 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1395">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="gridview-1396-record-6" data-boundview="gridview-1396" data-recordid="6" data-recordindex="1" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="  x-grid-row">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1392 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 126px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1392">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        195g
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1393 x-unselectable" style="width: 550px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1393">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
                        <span>CABALLA</span>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1394 x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1394">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        3,95
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1395 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1395">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        0,77
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="gridview-1396-record-5" data-boundview="gridview-1396" data-recordid="5" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="  x-grid-row">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1392 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable x-grid-item-focused" style="width: 126px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1392">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1393 x-unselectable" style="width: 550px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1393">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
                        <span>PESCADO</span>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1394 x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1394">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1395 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width: 168px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1395">
                    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Código Selenium Java:

```
String finPescadoEsperado = "FIN PESCADO";
WebElement panelVisible = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@style='margin: 0px; width: 1359px; height: 767px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px;']"));
        Waits.WaitUntilElementLocatedByXpath(".//span[text()='"+ pescado +"']");
        WebElement finPescadoElement = panelVisible.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='"+ finPescadoEsperado +"']"));
        String finPescado = finPescadoElement.getText();

        // Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(finPescadoEsperado, finPescado);
```

Comment: ¿No debes quitarle el punto que hay delante? `Waits.WaitUntilElementLocatedByXpath("//span[text()='"+ pescado +"']");`  y `WebElement finPescadoElement = panelVisible.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='"+ finPescadoEsperado +"']"));` ¿Y, cuál es el valor de `pescado`, puesto que no se ve en el contexto?

Comment: Intenta buscar directamente los span. Si la busqueda del panelVisible no te devuelve un WebElement puedes no encontrar el texto despues. Respecto al '.' se puede usar o no, no cambia el resultado. Y yo usaria en la busqueda de los dos span con el texto una busqueda con el Waits.WaitUntilElementLocatedByXpath.

Comment: muchas gracias! lo probaré!